# Notification System Design

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, database-schema

Given the schema below, how can a notification system be incorporated?

Users need to be notified when someone comments on their Picture or SaleItem along with when someone makes a bid on their SaleItem (through Purchase Offer).

The ultimate goal is to have a notification system that will handle SMS, Email, and an internal system messaging system.  The complexities of those options will be worked out but I need the basic data model from which they can be built upon.

MySql is the DB being used but I don't believe that should affect the data model.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does the person leaving a comment have to be a user? (That is, do they have to have a user id?)

Comment: @Catcall Yes any comments or PurchaseOffers will come from a User (CommenterId & BuyerId respectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup up a table for holding the notification information and set up a trigger to write to this table whenever there is an an action in the system (lets say new bid).

then your scheduler should pick this new notification and sends email/sms.